# How to download SharePoint page in PDF format?

Tags: sharepoint-server, pdf, download, pages, file-download

I want to download SharePoint pages(.aspx) in PDF format using Powershell or C# console application.

Is it possible?

Can you please share your thoughts or some reference code?

Comment: You can use some custom code to convert page into PDF using itextsharp or any other 3rd party DLL.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**:

You can export the SharePoint pages in PDF format using tools like `Muhimbi` or using some `dlls` in C# like `itextsharp`.

There are some similar threads on MSDN, please check below Links:

1. [Export SharePoint page to PDF](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/71e2177d-390c-4131-b09d-9ae3c34ef0b3/export-sharepoint-page-to-pdf?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious).
2. [Saving a SharePoint Page to PDF](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0fb1a530-8302-48f6-8957-c95d1c4bbe16/saving-a-sharepoint-page-to-pdf?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) .
3. [Sharepoint Online: Export pages to PDF](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/45062193-6d3c-4cd7-9a7e-8766bdd242cf/sharepoint-online-export-pages-to-pdf?forum=sharepointdevelopment) .
4. [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/) .

Also on browser(not sure all browsers supports or not) you can press `Ctrl+P`, it will allow you to save the SharePoint page to PDF.(It may not include everything in PDF as it is on page if there is any custom functionality on page).

Comment: Thanks for the 'shout out'. Surprisingly tricky topic, we have been working on this for years and the work never stops. Assuming this is about SharePoint on-premise, have a look at these HTML to PDF resources: https://support.muhimbi.com/hc/en-us/articles/228089127-Converting-SharePoint-pages-HTML

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but many tools (notably Adobe Acrobat) let you print any web page as a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button called Export to PDF in an HTML file then set the onclick event for the button.

More information, you can refer to the code provided in the following article:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/export-to-pdf-in-sharepoint