# Is there any way of exporting each entry in SharePoint list to PDF/word?

Tags: sharepoint-online, export, pdf, sharepoint-list

Is there any way of exporting each entry in SharePoint list to PDF/word. A scenario for example is "A SharePoint list contains the list of Participants for an event, I would like to export the each entry as a certificate for participants"

Comment: using OOTB functionalities in SharePoint is not possible. You can see my answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266191/how-to-download-sharepoint-page-in-pdf-format/266197#266197) for some alternatives

Comment: Are you using Modern View (in which case this is very tricky) or classic view?

Comment: I am fine with using Classic view if it is possible. @JeroenRitmeijer-Muhimbi

Comment: @DeepakNagaraj Have a look at http://blog.muhimbi.com/2017/10/converting-sharepoint-online-pages.html. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft Flow for generating a PDF file based on a SharePoint list item:
https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/intermediate-flow-of-the-week-create-pdf-invoices-using-word-templates-with-microsoft-flow/