# SP13 Quickest Way to get pages to pdf

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, powershell, wiki, aspx

Scenario:  I have a bunch of wiki page .aspx files maybe over 100 files. I want the quickest way to move those pages to 100 files into pdf and not open one page at a time.  This is a popular topic and I found many great converters but not helpful with batching and cost plays a part.  Right now I am using the "Save as PDF" in Edge and Chrome which works.  But there are more files than time to continue using Edge and Chrome.

Does anyone know the best way to convert .aspx files into pdf in multiples? Would PowerShell or creating a workflow in Flow or SharePoint Designer be the best way to go? Any help is needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think we can do that using PowerShell or Flow.

There actually is a **convert to pdf** action in Flow, but the target needs to be one of the following: files in OneDrive for Business, HTML files or data in Encodian and HTML files or data in Muhimbi. SharePoint aspx files are not supported. I’ve tried creating files and then convert to pdf, but it can only be done one at a time.

I think the closest thing you can get is what are mentioned in this similar post, third-party tools or custom solution:
[How to download SharePoint page in PDF format?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266191/how-to-download-sharepoint-page-in-pdf-format)